# How to keep browser from timing out when running offline javascript application

Tags: javascript, browser, kendo-ui

So I'm developing a Javascript/HTML program that behaves as an offline application which the user launches through an HTML file. The purpose of the application is to read a CSV file of very larger size, about 2 million rows long and the goal is to use KendoUI to create a scatter plot with this data (as a CSV vector). The library works well with data lengths of about 5-10 thousand, but at lengths 1 million+ long the browser stops to work, then crashes. Chrome for example says "aw snap", and quits. Would there be any way to prevent browsers from timing out like this? I was thinking of using Electron to allow it to run without a browser, but I think in the backend it's still on chromium, which would have the same limitations.

Comment: use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for running code on a separate thread and look through [PWA - Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) for concepts of running 'offline'

Answer (score 0):

read the file as a stream or slice the file in chunks and read one chunk at a time.